# Autocomplete mostra as opções mas não filtra conforme digitado

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

Sou principiante em JQuery e estou tendo o seguinte problema: Preciso de um input em que use o autocompletar para selecionar o município que eu quero. Ele exibe as opções, mas não está filtrando conforme o usuário digita, ficam sempre todas as opções disponíveis (como são todos os municípios brasileiros, dá mais de 5500). Abaixo estão meus códigos:

autocompletar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/js/jquery-ui.css">
    
<script src="libs/js/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="libs/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#municipio').autocomplete({
        minLenght: 4,
        source: "municipios.php"
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="municipio">
    <input type="text" id="coordenada">
</body>
</html>
```

O array gerado pelo arquivo municipios.php está ok, conforme segue:
["Abaíra-BA","Abaré-BA","Abatiá-PR","Abdon Batista-SC","Abel Figueiredo-PA","Abelardo Luz-SC",
...
"Zabelê-PB","Zacarias-SP","Zé Doca-MA","Zortéa-SC"]

Outro problema que detectei é que ao digitar no input, não está aguarando o minLenght, já no primeiro caracter digitado aparecem todos os municípios.

Agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Se não esta utilizando nenhuma consulta no banco de dados, pode-se procurar diretamente no array do lado do servidor PHP:
Exemplo:

```
$input = preg_quote($valorDigitadoNoAutoComplete, '~');
$data = ["Abaíra-BA","Abaré-BA","Abatiá-PR","Abdon Batista-SC","Abel Figueiredo-PA","Abelardo Luz-SC", ... "Zabelê-PB","Zacarias-SP","Zé Doca-MA","Zortéa-SC"]

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
```

Outro detalhe importante o ***minLenght*** esta escrito errado, seria ***minLength***, por esse motivo não funciona.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Já solucionei, realmente estava errado o minLength. O Php estava gerando espaços em branco antes do array(erro meu, tinha colocado um echo antes e esqueci de apagar). Obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta foi util, coloque como certa. :)